# How do I add a boot parameter to grub2 in Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, grub2

I got my Ubuntu server built and working, but I have to manually add a boot parameter ("no-hlt") into grub to start. I'm running maverick so it's grub2..and I can't figure out how to put it in so I don't have to manually override it on every boot. What exactly do I need to do to include this parameter in the default boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="no-hit"
```

If you only need it on normal boot (i.e. not single-user mode):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="no-hit"
```

If there are already options there, then either append or prepend (doesn't really matter which) using spaces as delimiters.

---

Some might say to edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`; this is a bad idea, as Grub2 automatically overwrites this file every time anything involving the kernel or GRUB is updated.

Comment: Perfect, that did it. The only other step was after updating that file, was to run sudo update-grub. Thanks for the tip!